# How to get rid of small space between numbers in list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, whitespace

I grouped my data frame, as shown in the photo and I noticed there is like a small space between the numbers. Is this normal? Do I need to get rid of it or it doesn't affect anything?

[Photo of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WsTw.png)

Update: I have tried .str.strip() method but everything in the path column became NaN

Update: This is what I get when I try the print option:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUWDF.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is normal it won't affect any computation that you want to do ahead, though I have not encountered such an error it seems to be just a visualization thing, still, if you wish to make sure that there aren't any spaces in the list you can make the following change in this particular line of code.

```py
df1 = df.groupby('jid').aggregate({'conversion': 'sum', 'path': lambda x: [int(n) for n in x.tolist()]}).reset_index()
```

It is a pretty naive approach any suggestions are appreciated.

**EDIT:**
My previous suggestion was actually wrong, try this code it isn't doing anything special just iterating over the list made from `.tolist()` method and converting them to integers, this makes sure there won't be any spaces

Comment: Unfortunately I get an attribute error of AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) in lambda function:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('jid').agg({'conversion':'sum', 'path': lambda x: x.str.strip().tolist()})
        .reset_index())
```

Or before `groupby` with reaasing back values by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(path = df['path'].str.strip()).groupby('jid')
         .agg({'conversion': 'sum', 'path': lambda x: x.tolist()})
         .reset_index())
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'path':[' 1','3','5' ,' 7 ','1',' 0'],
         'conversion':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'jid':list('aaabbb')
})

df1 = (df.groupby('jid').agg({'conversion':'sum', 'path': lambda x: x.str.strip().tolist()})
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
  jid  conversion       path
0   a          14  [1, 3, 5]
1   b          15  [7, 1, 0]

df1 = (df.assign(path = df['path'].str.strip()).groupby('jid')
         .agg({'conversion': 'sum', 'path': lambda x: x.tolist()})
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  jid  conversion       path
0   a          14  [1, 3, 5]
1   b          15  [7, 1, 0]
```

Original:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('jid')
         .agg({'conversion': 'sum', 'path': lambda x: x.tolist()})
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  jid  conversion          path
0   a          14    [ 1, 3, 5]
1   b          15  [ 7 , 1,  0]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast reply! In the end it was still the same with the white space. So maybe Shaikh is correct, it is just a visual thing and won't affect when i create my models.

Comment: @Rickboekhoudt - It is easy test, try `print(df['path'].tolist())` for check if traling whitespaces

Comment: Yes, I tried and to me, it looks like there are spaces after the commas. I added a photo in the update

Comment: @Rickboekhoudt - yes, I see it too in your picture. So no difference after my solution?